# What can I do if SqlDelight does not support the POINT data type in Postgres?

Tags: sqldelight

As it looks like based on the [documentation](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jvm_postgresql/types/) about SqlDelight, there is no support for the [`Point` Datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-geometric.html#idm46428712347808).

Given that I'd rather not want to match the database to a library, let's assume for the sake of this example that I have an existing database with the `Point` datatype. How can I write insert statements?

Unfortunately, I cannot even write the following in `apartment.sq` file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE apartment(
    id              BIGSERIAL   NOT NULL,
    location        POINT
);
```

Error:

> <type name real> expected, got 'POINT'

I haven't tested adapters, but to my understanding if I declare this table with a different underlying data type, wrong statements would be generated anyway when trying to insert a point.